# Importing files from different dir

Tags: python-3.x, python-importlib, import-module

I am working on a project where my python file (which is located in D:) will open the 'submissions' folder (`in C:\user\desktop\`). Now, submissions folder has sub-folders of students like student1, student2, etc. Now, each student submits the same file say `my_math.py` (which has add, sub, mul,. functions).

So, my program (`test_math.py`) tests each of their submissions one after another.

```
addr = r'C:\users\desktop\submissions\student1'
import importlib
module = importlib.import_module('test_math', package = addr)
```

This doesn't seem to work. I also have a `__init__.py` in submissions folder. I don't know where the problem is! I'm using `python 3.6.3`

Comment: You should have a look at the os module for everything related to folder / file navigation, especially in your case to os.walk: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm

Comment: I am able to get all the folders in that location using `os.listdir`. But what i want is to import all those __same files__ dynamically one after another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two methods:

One, from command line: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH . I think you should start a new python interpreter at every student.

or just inside python, before import, you manipulate `sys.path` https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path

But when your studend know that you execute the code directly from your console, they will abuse the system (as they always did).

Comment: can i not use `importlib.import_moduie` to import files from other directories?

Comment: @SreekarMouli: yes, but it do no matter. `import_module` is a sort of `import`, but you cannot specify path. As you see https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#functions you are not using it as you should do it. Your first argument is not relative, and the second should not be a path.